# Move mouse pointer to GTK widget

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Does anybody know how to move a mouse pointer to a specific Gtk widget with Python code? Google does not seem to yield any results. I want to hover the pointer over the print button when popping up the GtkPrintOperation dialog. Theoretically, the code should work with any Gtk widget. What I found so far: you can get the position of the mouse. However, I need to set the position of the mouse. If I need to rewrite the whole Gtk stack it probably won't happen. One alternative would be to set the GtkButton as the default and then ENTER would print the document without moving the mouse to select the button.

Why I need this: the project is for my brother in law who is using OpenOffice Basic and he has this feature. I would definitely like to make an impression with Gtk (which is way more powerful). As he prints a lot of documents this is very needed. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible with pure Gtk.  There is `Xlib`, but that isn't Gtk.

Comment: Moving the mouse cursor without the user actually moving the mouse is typically a very bad idea as it defies user expectation ("wtf? where did my cursor disappear? It was right there!"). There are valid use cases for it -- like impressing ones brother -- but they are not common enough for GTK to offer an API for it.

Answer (score 0):

In X-Windows, you can use xdotool:

```
$ xdotool mousemove column row
```

Comment: But how is one supposed to know where the widget is?